# How can I automatically detect a proxy?

Tags: qt

For one of my projects, I made a QWebView. Everything is working fine, but when I use it at school, I get an error because the proxy is not defined. How would I make it possible to auto detect the proxy, like in Firefox and IE?

I've found this in [`QNetworkProxyFactory`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qnetworkproxyfactory.html):

```
setUseSystemConfiguration(bool enable)
```

But I can't find how to use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `setUseSystemConfiguration` is a static method, the following might do what you need:

```
QNetworkProxyFactory::setUseSystemConfiguration(true);
```

Comment: That would probably be a good place for it. Just make that call before you create your QWebView.

Comment: When i try to use it, i got 18 errors similar to this :
erreur : undefined reference to `_imp___ZN20QNetworkProxyFactory25setUseSystemConfigurationEb'

Comment: You might need to add `QT += network` to your `.pro` file. See https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtnetwork.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of using the system defined proxy:

```
QNetworkProxyQuery npq(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
QList<QNetworkProxy> listOfProxies = QNetworkProxyFactory::systemProxyForQuery(npq);
if (listOfProxies.size())
    QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(listOfProxies[0]);
```

Comment: Yes. This set the proxy application-wide.