# Qt request dynamic XML from Web

Tags: xml, qt, dynamic, httpwebrequest

I learn `Qt` and I want to download a XML file from the Internet. 
The `QUrl` is depending on further values value1 and value2; example:

> http://www.example.org/path/the_xml_file.xml?value1=1&value2=2

Here I set the `QString` destination_XML_URL

```
void AClass::setUrlString(quint32 t_value1, quint32 t_value2) {
    destination_XML_URL = QString("http://www.anyweb.com/path/the_xml_file.xml?value1=%1&value2=%2").arg(t_value1).arg(t_value2);
}
```

Then I request that location with a `QUrl` in a method:

```
QNetworkAccessManager url_network_access_manager;
//..;
setTarget(12, 34);  
QUrl xml_Url(destination_XML_URL);
QNetworkRequest request(xml_Url);
QNetworkReply url_network_reply = url_network_access_manager.get(request);
```

Finally connecting the connect:

```
connect(&url_network_access_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(slot_disconnect2Net(QNetworkReply*)));
```

Then the slot, after retrieving the xml file from web:

```
void AClass::slot_disconnect2Net(QNetworkReply *data) {
    qint64 t_size1 = data->size();
    int error_code = data->error();
    switch(error_code) {
        case 0:
            transform_Raw_2_XML(data);
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 301:
            break;  
        default:
            QMessageBox::critical(this, "AClass::disconnect2Net()", QString("Connection error %1:\n %2").arg(error_code).arg(data->errorString()), QMessageBox::Ok);
    }
}
```

But I get error_code 3:

> http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#NetworkError-enum
>
> "QNetworkReply::HostNotFoundError = 3 : the remote host name was not
>   found (invalid hostname)"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible, that your connection is behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes, there is a proxy: //QNetworkProxy proxy; //proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy); //proxy.setHostName("web.name.net"); //proxy.setPort(8080); //proxy.setUser("username"); //proxy.setPassword("*******"); //QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy); //url_network_access_manager.setProxy(proxy); With that I get QNetworkReply::ProxyAuthenticationRequiredError 105 the proxy requires authentication in order to honour the request but did not accept any credentials offered (if any)

Comment: the text says: "Proxy requires authentication"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like network connection not available.  It is not an error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This cryptic error message means that the remote host name was not found (invalid hostname) ;-)

Looks like a proxy dns issue. Please try replacing the host name with the ip address (`208.73.210.29`?)

Comment: In the browser, I can see the content.

Comment: Well, looks like your real (at least at first) problem is the proxy one. see <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526473/how-can-i-automatically-detect-a-proxy>

Comment: But, QUrl url = QUrl("http://www.aai.dfn.de/fileadmin/metadata/DFN-AAI-Test-metadata.xml", QUrl::ParsingMode::TolerantMode); can retrieve with that proxy settings above. Another QUrl with that mentioned dynamic the_xml_file.xml?value1=1&value2=2 above, I get that errormessage.